# .htaccess to remove html from url not working

Tags: html, .htaccess

I want to rewrite: www.example.com/guides.html to www.example.com/guides

I rewrote the htaccess file using almost every version found here in stackoverflow and could get it to work.

Im currently navigating to the url like this:

```
<a href="/guides.html"> GUIDES </a>
```

If i try in my development server using:

```
http://localhost:3000/guides
```

I get

> "Cannot GET /guides".

If i try it in my production server I get:

> "Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.>
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A691200
ExpiresByType image/png A691200
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A691200
ExpiresByType text/css A691200
ExpiresByType text/javascript A691200
ExpiresByType application/javascript A691200
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
#Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####

#### PERSISTENT CONTENT END ####

DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(js\/main\.js|css\/(\d+|common|site)\.css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitepro/$1 [L,QSA]

#### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

And here's how i modified it:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A691200
ExpiresByType image/png A691200
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A691200
ExpiresByType text/css A691200
ExpiresByType text/javascript A691200
ExpiresByType application/javascript A691200
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
#Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####

#### PERSISTENT CONTENT END ####

DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(js\/main\.js|css\/(\d+|common|site)\.css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitepro/$1 [L,QSA]

#### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]


## hide .php extension
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out by chance I stumbled upon an article that mention that i needed 'Options +MultiViews' before writing the rules. It is working now, at least for my production server.